# Как запустить gcc 7.3? Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

Уже установлена версия gcc-9.3.0 и gcc-7.5.0, но при этом неизвестно как запустить gcc-7.3.0, система автоматически ставит 7.5.0. Слышал что можно скачивать tar.xz архив и там найти исполняемый файл и вызвать через него. Архив я скачал, но он содержит огромное количество папок и не понятно как найти то что мне нужно. Есть актуальное решение проблемы?

Comment: Есть, и оно очевидно (собрать из уже имеющихся у вас исходников), но, судя по описанной вами ситуации, оно вам вряд ли подойдёт. А чем вызвана необходимость в именно 7.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

В каталоге /usr/bin создайте две символические ссылки:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s <Путь до седьмой версии> gcc7
sudo ln -s <Путь до девятой версии> gcc9
```

После этого будете запускать их соответственно: gcc7 или gcc9.